# I need to generate a random date, MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: ruby

I need to generate a random Date.
I do not need time in my calculation.
What I am trying to use is:

```
def date_rand from = 0.0, to = Time.now
  Time.at(from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f))
end
```

This gets me close, but has a bunch other information I do not need. (time, zone, etc.)
If there is a way to get the date without all the other data I would appreciate some help on knowing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, including the `date` library adds a `#to_date` method to the `Time` class (as well as a `#to_datetime` method). Ruby 1.8 has it too, but it's a private method.

```
require 'date'
def date_rand(from = 0.0, to = Time.now)
  Time.at(from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f)).to_date
end
```

In Ruby 1.8, you could do something like this:

```
def date_rand(from = 0.0, to = Time.now)
   time = Time.at(from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f))
   Date.civil(time.year, time.month, time.day)
end
```

Comment: So I am using the Ruby 1.8 version and it works great!!! But, I need to be able to change the format for it. I get "1979-02-19" but I need "02-19-1979". If you know of a quick way to do this that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Both methods return a `Date` object. Calling `to_s` on a `Date` object defaults to `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You can use strftime instead: `date_rand.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")`

Answer (score 2):

dmarkov's answer is fine. You can do the same with dates:

```
require 'date'
def date_rand(from = Date.new(1970,1,1), to = Date.today)
  low, high = from.ajd.to_i, to.ajd.to_i
  r = rand(high-low+1) + low
  Date.jd(r)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From a [blog post](http://jroller.com/obie/entry/quickly_generate_random_dates_in) by Obie Fernandez.

```
class Time
  def self.random(years_back=5)
    year = Time.now.year - rand(years_back) - 1
    month = rand(12) + 1
    day = rand(31) + 1
    Time.local(year, month, day)
  end
end
```

This allows you to call Time.random. I'm presenting this as an alternate answer to your question and depending on how you're planning on using this, please be careful as monkey patching the standard lib classes isn't usually the best way to go about things if someone else is going to have to debug/support your code one of these days.